# python When writing to csv file, why does it loop forever with same row?

Tags: python, csv

```
rows = get_rows() #returns a list of rows
for row in rows:       
  with open('output.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    try:
      data = compute(row['id']) #does some transforming of data on the row['id'] string data
    except Exception:
      pass
    print data
    a.writerow(data)
```

output:

```
row1
row1
row1
row1
```

it keeps on going

I expected:

```
row1
row2
row3
row4
row5
so on
```

Comment: What does `get_rows()` return?

Comment: seems like you are reopening your file on each iteration, you should move it outside of the for loop

Comment: Why is your output file opening code inside the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is your *entire* problem, but the lines:

```
for row in rows:       
  with open('output.csv', 'w') as fp:
```

should be the other way around. As written, this will open the file and close it once for every row - which is a lot of extra work than what you need to be doing. More importantly, it will *truncate* the file each time around the loop - losing all the previous work, and eventually leaving you with only one line in the file. Do it this way instead:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for row in rows:
       ...
```